# Dsicord.py: Command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to set up some commands for my discord.py bot and when I give the command `!add_country "xyz"`, it works how it's intended to work. But when I give the command `!add_role_msg {msg id}` which is located right below the previous command and is almost identical, it throws an error saying `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "add_role_msg" is not found`. Is there something I'm missing? Someone pls point it out. Thanks in advance!

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions

import nicknamecheck
import rolereaction

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

msg_id = 0

@bot.command(name = "add_country", pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)  
async def add_country(ctx, arg):
    with open('countries.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(f"""\n{arg}""")
    await ctx.channel.send(f"""Added {arg} to the list of countries""")

@add_country.error
async def add_country_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to do that!")


@bot.command(name = "add_role_message", pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)  
async def add_role_msg(ctx, arg):
    msg_id = arg 
    print("KK")    

@add_role_msg.error
async def add_role_msg(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("You don't have permission to do that!")


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == msg_id:
        print(payload.emoji.name)
        # Find a role corresponding to the Emoji name.
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)

        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r : r.name == payload.emoji.name, guild.roles)

        if role is not None:
            print(role.name + " was found!")
            print(role.id)
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            await member.add_roles(role)
            print("done")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 'id':
        print(payload.emoji.name)

        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, bot.guilds)
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r : r.name == payload.emoji.name, guild.roles)

        if role is not None:
            member = discord.utils.find(lambda m : m.id == payload.user_id, guild.members)
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print("done")
            

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    print(f'{bot.guilds}')

    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

    await nicknamecheck.nicknameCheck(message)       
    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `!add_role_message {msg id}`

You have specified command name different of the function name:

- function name: `add_role_msg`
- command name: `add_role_message`